# Getting a value from a javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string in javascript.

```
var X = "<tr><td>pro</td><td>intel</td><td>234</td></tr>"
```

How can I retrieve the value 234 to another variable from that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've heard the disclaimers about parsing html with regex, but if you want regex, with your input, you can use this pattern:

```
[^><]+(?=<\/td><\/tr>)
```

In JS:

```
var myregex = /[^><]+(?=<\/td><\/tr>)/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = "<tr><td>pro</td><td>intel</td><td>234</td></tr>";
var res = x.match(/\d+/);
console.log(res[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex to get the value inside last `<td>` tag,

```
[^<>]*(?=<\/td><\/tr>$)
```

Code would be,

```
> var X = "<tr><td>pro</td><td>intel</td><td>234</td></tr>"
undefined
> var out = X.match(/[^<>]*(?=<\/td><\/tr>$)/g);
undefined
> console.log(out[0]);
234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using XPath expressions:

```
/tr/td[3]/text()
```

Javascript and XPath are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

for *this* string:

```
var X = "<tr><td>pro</td><td>intel</td><td>234</td></tr>"
         .match(/\d+/)[0];
```

should be sufficient